# Fix the difference between Float and Numeric field types

Tags: vb.net, dbf

I have two dbf tables and must compare them by column (field) types. For example:

Table1: `Id (Numeric) | Name (Character) | Salary (Numeric)`
Table2: `Id (Numeric) | Name (Character) | Salary (Float)`

With these two tables program should display message like (types do not match in field `SALARY [F <> N]`) where F is float and N is numeric.

So I can't find the difference between this fields because for both tables

```
    Using cmd2 As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("select * from Table1", connection)
                    Dim reader As OleDb.OleDbDataReader
                    reader = cmd2.ExecuteReader()

    reader.GetDataTypeName(2) 'returns DBTYPE_NUMERIC
    reader.GetFieldType(2) 'returns System.Decimal
End Using

    Using cmd3 As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("select * from Table2", connection)
                    Dim reader2 As OleDb.OleDbDataReader
                    reader2 = cmd3.ExecuteReader()

    reader2.GetDataTypeName(2) 'returns DBTYPE_NUMERIC
    reader2.GetFieldType(2) 'returns System.Decimal
End Using
```

I can view 'F' and 'N' characters in dbf header by opening dbf file in Notepad but can't read it to VB and I don't think it's good idea too.

What can I do with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The `F` and `N` types are exactly the same, there is no difference between them.

A more useful distinction would be their setup, as you can specify how many digits and how many decimal places are stored in the field.

Unfortunately, I do not know how to check for that in VB.Net.